# Moving images from Docker registry to GCR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

Google cloud run does not support the docker registry, therefore I have to manually pull the image, tag it and push it to GCR.

> Container image URL should match pattern [region.]gcr.io/repo-path[:tag or @digest]

Is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: Use GCR to start with and don't use Docker for your Cloud Run images. One reason that only GCR is supported is Cloud Run implements container load technology (sparse loads) behind the scenes to reduce container startup times.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm not the maintainer of the project that I'm trying to run, images of the project are released in docker hub so I have to pull it, tag it and push to GCR, which is a network-intensive task. So I was wondering if there is any easier way to copy images from dockerhub to GCR.

Comment: I am not aware of a tool. I would use Docker Hub Web Hooks and Cloud Run. Then everything is automatic. https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/webhooks/ This will require a bit of code on your side. There might be some good examples on the Internet.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, that's the easiest way to move a Docker image from one container registry to another one.

Just for documentation purposes, I will add the steps for the benefit of the community:

1. Pull the Docker image using the following command:

> docker pull [REPOSITORY-NAME]/[IMAGE]:[TAG]

2. Then, tag that pulled image using the following command:

> docker tag [IMAGE] gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]

3. Push that image to your gcr repository using the following command:

> docker push gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]

Comment: This is the method that I'm currently using, but doing this for multiple images is very network intensive.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on some tooling called [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) that supports this use case. For copying a single image, the command would be:

```
regctl image copy ${source} ${target}
```

e.g.

```
regctl image copy ubuntu:latest gcr.io/your-project/ubuntu:latest
```

This checks the digests before copying with a HEAD request to allow the command to be run frequently but only using your quota when the upstream image doesn't match what's on GCR. It also copies multi-platform images which you wouldn't get with a `docker pull` and `docker push` (docker dereferences the image to your platform on the pull). And unlike the `docker pull`, the individual layers are only copied when they don't exist on the target registry.

If you have lots of images to continuously mirror, there's also a `regsync` command that copies according to a yaml file with a list of images, tags, and schedule to run the copies.

These can run as containers, but they are also available as standalone binaries that don't require docker to run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid in any case, "simpler" won't be a thing. Though, you may try to use [Docker web hooks](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/webhooks/) to call a simple Cloud function (pull, tag, push) in order to keep your images in sync in your GCR.

There seems to be some projects to manage that kind of hassle like [dregsy](https://github.com/xelalexv/dregsy) but I didn't try them...